# Interpretation of a Limiting Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem, order-statistics

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be random variables independent and identically distributed on $Uniform(0,1)$.  Let $Y_{(n)}=MAX{(X_1,...,X_n)}$.  Define $W_n=n(1-Y_{(n)})$.
Find the limiting distribution of $W_n$ as $n$ increases without bound.  Can you identify this limiting distribution?
Give an interpretation of the result obtained above.

So, I managed to find that the limiting distribution follows an exponential distribution with mean 1.  However, I'm not quite sure how to "interpret" this.  **What's so special about $W_n$ that makes this result significant when $n$ grows large?**  Is there some intuitive understanding to this that I'm just not seeing?

Comment: I would like to humbly request a notation change from $X_{(n)}=MAX(X_1, ..., X_n)$ to $Y_n = MAX(X_1, ..., X_n)$.  So then $W_n = n(1-Y_n)$.

Comment: My own 2 cents on interpretation (others can likely word it better):  Since $Y_n$ is getting very close to 1, $1-Y_n$ is getting very close to $0$, so without scaling by $n$, the value $1-Y_n$ just goes to zero.  The significance of $n(1-Y_n)$ is that it shows, when these very small values are scaled, the (scaled) "deviation from zero" looks exponential, which is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible explanation. Mathematically, it's pretty meaningless, but may shed a light on the emergence of exponential distribution.

Instead of $W_n$, let us look at $V_n=n\min_{1\le k \le n} X_k$, which has the same distribution. It is a minimum of $n$ iid variables, uniform on $[0,n]$. Then its limit $W_\infty$ is a "minimum of infinitely many random variables, uniformly distributed on $[0,\infty)$". What is the distribution of $W_\infty - t$ given $W_\infty > t$? It is the distribution of minimum of infinitely many random variables, uniformly distributed on $[t,\infty)$, minus $t$; this is the distribution of $W_\infty$. So $W_\infty$ has no memory, hence the exponential distribution.